# How Can I nest two foreach to get right values output?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I have two `foreach` blocks to get some values from a web page (I'm scraping values from an HTML table).

```php
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/belgium/jupiler-league/results/');

foreach($html->find('td') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
}   

foreach( $html->find('td[data-odd]') as $td ) {
    echo $td->attr['data-odd'].PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

and this is my HTML code:

```html
<tr class="strong">
    <td class="first-cell tl">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=z7jbSp5K" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Waasland-Beveren - Anderlecht</a>
    </td>
    <td class="result">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=z7jbSp5K" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">1:0</a>
    </td>
    <td class="odds best-betrate" data-odd="5.97"></td>
    <td class="odds" data-odd="4.21"></td>
    <td class="odds" data-odd="1.51"></td>
    <td class="last-cell nobr date">21.02.2016</td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
    <td class="first-cell tl">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=x0YB63r1" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Waregem - KV Mechelen</a>
    </td>
    <td class="result">
        <a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=x0YB63r1" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">2:3</a>
    </td>
    <td class="odds" data-odd="1.83"></td><td class="odds" data-odd="3.71"></td>
    <td class="odds best-betrate" data-odd="3.99"></td>
    <td class="last-cell nobr date">21.02.2016</td>
</tr>
```

In this way, in my output, I get before values from the first foreach and, after, values from the second. I'd like to get values together in the right order. For example:

```
21.02.2016 Waasland-Beveren - Anderlecht 1:0 5.96 4.20 1.51   
21.02.2016 Waregem - KV Mechelen 2:3 1.83 3.71 3.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have the exact (count) or (length). Use the normal `for` after you assign them to two variables.

```
$td = $html->find('td');
$attr = $html->find('td[data-odd]');

for($i=0; $i < count($td); $i++) 
     echo $td[$i]->innertext."<br/>".$attr[$i]->attr['data-odd'].PHP_EOL;
```

---

#### Update:

You want to reorder the tds you received from the HTML file, that means you have to think of another logic in how to retrieve them. This updated code is very specific to your case:

```
$match_dates = $html->find("td[class=last-cell nobr date]"); // we have 1 per match
$titles = $html->find("td[class=first-cell tl]"); // 1 per match
$results = $html->find("td[class=result]"); // 1
$best_bets = $html->find("td[class=odds best-betrate]"); // 1
$odds = $html->find("td[class=odds]"); // 2

// Now to output everything in whatever order you want:

$c=0; $b=0; // two counters
foreach($titles as $match)
    echo $match_dates[$c]->innertext." - ".$match->innertext." [".$results[$c]->innertext."] - Best bet rate: ".$best_bets[$c++]->attr['data-odd']." - odds: ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd'].", ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd']."<br/>";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried it but i got just a blank page. How Can I fix it, please? :)

Comment: @marcellogabrielli Pardon me, I updated the answer. The problem was with count(). I didn't execute the code, but if your code works, this one must work too.

Comment: Ok, thanks! it's almost perfect and I marked it with the right answer, but Can I ask just a thing? My output now is like this: 
Oostende - Gent 3.95 5:2 3.51 1.89 5.97 4.21 21.02.2016 1.51 Waasland-Beveren - Anderlecht 1.83 1:0 3.71 3.99 1.72 3.62 21.02.2016 
But I need to have something like this: 
Waasland-Beveren - Anderlecht 1:0 5.96 4.20 1.51 21.02.2016 //first row

Waregem - KV Mechelen 2:3 1.83 3.71 3.98 21.02.2016 //second row

Comment: @marcellogabrielli I updated the answer, hope it fits your conditions :) HaGD

Comment: It's perfect!!! Thank you! I don't want to press you anymore so I will try to split just the result by myself to have single number (1:0 -> 1 0). Thanks again!!! :)

Comment: @marcellogabrielli You're always welcome. For the result you want, replace it with `str_replace(':',' ',$results[$c]->innertext)`, replacing the `:` with a space or even nothing.

Comment: Sorry but where I should replace it? This is my last request, I promise it :)

Comment: @marcellogabrielli look at the last line, replace the `$results[$c]->innertext` with `str_replace(':',' ',$results[$c]->innertext)`. You don't have to change anything else.